# Script to disable/enable Network Connection

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, netsh, startupscript

I am rebuilding an old Toshiba laptop for my kid to play on to see if it is worth buying something decent come Christmas; e.g. I'm looking for zero cost solutions, no hardware upgrades.

The network adapter in incompatible with windows 8.1 such that when the laptop starts the wireless won't connect.
There are no Windows 8.1 drivers as the network adapter is unsupported.

By going to the network properties and disabling and then enabling the adapter the problem clears and I get stable wireless connection.

What I would like is a start up script to do the disable/enable routine I currently do by hand.

I have tried using:

```
netsh interface set interface "WiFi" DISABLE
netsh interface set interface "Wifi" ENABLE
```

in a Batch file and whilst it runs on demand it seems a bit hit and miss when run as a start-up task

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

netsh is dependent on wlansvc, so you may be experiencing a race between your script running and wlansvc completing startup. At the beginning of your script you could add

```
net start wlansvc
```

And that may help ensure wlansvc is started since net start will not return until the service has finished starting (or will return immediately if the service is already started)